# Solution for Kummer's kind of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A better presented solution of the following ODE:
\begin{equation}
xy''(x)+(a-bx)y'(x)+cy(x)=0
\end{equation}
under boundary conditions, 
\begin{align}
y(0)&=0,\\
sy'(-1)&=y(-1)-1.
\end{align}
Assuming $g>0,$ for $c=gb.$

With the help of Mathemtica, the solution looks like:
\begin{equation}\label{flux}
y(x)=\frac{U(-g,a,0) L_g^{a-1}(b x)-L_g^{a-1}(0) U(-g,a,b x)}{b U(-g,a,0) L_{g-1}^a(-b)+b g L_g^{a-1}(0) U(1-g,a+1,-b)-L_g^{a-1}(0) U(-g,a,-b)+U(-g,a,0) L_g^{a-1}(-b)}
\end{equation} 
which to me looks weird. Looking for any other (form of) solution. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use Mathematica,focus first on the solution of the equation
$$xy''+(a-bx)y'+cy=0$$ It should be given as
$$y=c_1 U\left(-\frac{c}{b},a,b x\right)+c_2 L_{\frac{c}{b}}^{a-1}(b x)$$ Now, for sure, introducing the conditions leads to your "monster".

I do not think that you could be able to find other forms (except, *may be*, for some specific conditions for $(a,b,c)$ (the case where $\frac c b$ is an integer just leads to polynomials).

Comment: Well, I may assume it then, that $\frac{c}{b}$ is an integer. Because, in my case,  $(a, b, c)$ are assigned values to some other cumbersome set of parameters.  Would it be nearly possible to get any nicer solution? Maple Software produces even a more complicated form.

Comment: @Waqar. Let the equation as it is. Ignore the conditions. Set $c=k b$ and compute $y_k$ ($k>0)

Comment: Thanks for your great help.